# Preventing spaces in input on material ui (mui)

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, material-ui

```
    <FormControl variant="standard">
        <InputLabel className="input-box-label" htmlFor="component-helper">My Value</InputLabel>
        <Input
          id="component-helper"
          value={myValue}
          onChange={handleChangeMyValue}
        />
    </FormControl>
```

In this block of code, I'm wanting to make sure a user can't put any spaces as part of `myValue`. I can't really work out from the docs https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/ how to put validation on form inputs (this includes adding other restraints such as only lower case letters, or any regex pattern for example).

Another aside thought, are forms redundant when one is dealing with 'state' as opposed to 'submitting' a form as would happen when not writing a single page app with a system like React? What is the benefit of actually having a `<form>` element in there if nothing is ever `submitted`?

Comment: Angular performs the form validation piece: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation
Material only gives you the basic input components.

If this field is standalone and not part of a submitted form, you don't really need the form element. From experience, I suggest keeping form data out of state until it's submitted.

Edit: if you are using an Angular Form Group, the form element is what ties the HTML template form to the form group. This would be a good reason to keep the form element.

Comment: ah forgot to mention, I'm using React, but the same principles will apply

Answer (score 1):

```
onChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({firstName: e.target.value.trim()})
}
```

Comment: You should add explanation.